# Sortable and droppable deactivate in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have attached jQuery UI sortable and droppable to a few different pages on my page.

I want to have the elements that are dropped, not end up in the closest column to the 'droppable' column after the user has dragged across another active column.

http://jsfiddle.net/jordanbaucke/W3yyk/4/

I have tried to disable the closest 'sortable' column and reactivate when 'droppable' is active, but this doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you looking to have the 'dropped' element disappear from the sortable column or stay in the originating column?

Comment: @dSquared stay in the originating column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add utilize the $.sortable('cancel') method on the $.droppable 'drop' event to like this:

```
$('#droppablecolumn').droppable({
    over: function(en, ui) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'grey');
    },

    out: function(en, ui) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    },

    drop: function(){
        $('.column').sortable('cancel');    
    }    
});
```

This should cancel the current $.sortable event once a drop has occurred.

Comment: right on, _except the source column no longer seems to be sortable_? I tried reactivating `$('.column').sortable()` but it doesn't reattach to that element? _All the other columns remain active??_ so close...

Comment: **figured it out** ... this strategy works much better when you don't use a 'revert'

Comment: how did you resolve it? I have the same problem after calling .sortable('cancel') on drop event, the source column  loose sorttable